# How to looping grid in PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach, grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhZxp.png)

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h3>
        <small class="post-date">Posted on: <?php echo $post['created_at']; ?> in <strong><?php echo $post['name']; ?></strong></small>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the problem i have is every time the looping is the same result

as shown below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhitg.png)

My question can any one help me come with a PHP loop at works better than mine and does not leave any syntax errors with any given image count?

Comment: Show your complete code for your loop.

Comment: as it is my code, I think it should use an if statement but I can not use it

Comment: you've set `col-md-4` for all elements inside the loop. That's the reason they have the same dimensions. What is it you're trying to achieve here as the content of your loop is different from your desired output which is a well organized page.

Comment: if i want to replace it into a custom grid what should i do?

Comment: just change this `col-md-4` to fit what you one. What do you expect to happen if your blog post exceeds 6? As your current desired output only has 6 grids in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code it looks like a lot but that's because I had to create an array to simulate the data you receive.

```
//create an array that contains the column sizes we want in order
<?php $gridLayoutConfig = array("col-md-12", "col-md-8", "col-md-4", "col-md-3", "col-md-3", "col-md-3"); ?>
//here I am simulating data since I dont have your data
<?php $posts = array(
array("title" => "Mean Streets", "name" => "Meaner Streets", "created_at" => "0000"), 
array("title" => "Mean Streets 2", "name" => "Meaner Streets 2" , "created_at" => "0000"), 
array("title" => "Mean Streets 3", "name" => "Meaner Streets 3", "created_at" => "0000"),
array("title" => "Mean Streets 4", "name" => "Meaner Streets 4", "created_at" => "0000"),
array("title" => "Mean Streets 5", "name" => "Meaner Streets 5", "created_at" => "0000"),
array("title" => "Mean Streets 6", "name" => "Meaner Streets 6", "created_at" => "0000")
);  ?>
<?php $i = 0; ?>
//create container row outside the foreach
<?php echo "<div class='row'>"; ?>
<?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
//set divs class to whatever count is currently (0 = "col-md-12", 1 = "col-md-8")
//divide count by how many entries in our gridLayoutConfig  by whatever $i that means when we reach the last array entry $i % count($gridLayoutConfig) roll back around to equal 0 starting the layout again.
<?php echo '<div class="'.$gridLayoutConfig[$i % count($gridLayoutConfig)].'">' ?>
        <h3><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h3>
        <small class="post-date">Posted on: <?php echo $post['created_at']; ?> in <strong> 
        <?php echo $post['name']; ?></strong></small>
    </div>
<?php $i++; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php echo "</div>"; ?>
```

Also added a PHPFiddle to better demonstrate open the link press F9 to run then check the inspector and you will see each div has the correct class it will not display properly in the fiddle as there is no bootstrap included but should work fine in your own page.

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/aei9-tw86

You see in the php fiddle when we reach "Mean Streets 7" the $gridLayoutConfig starts from the beginning ($gridLayoutConfig[0]) again and will repeat the pattern.